# Laravel equivalent of a service with Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a Symfony developer learning Laravel 4, and I'd like to use what is under Symfony called a "Service".

I created a file called "services" and put a class called TestService.php inside.

Then I called it like this in the routes :

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    $test = new \services\TestService();
    $test->sayHello();
});
```

Can you tell what I did wrong ? Or if there is a better way to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Why laravel 4? The latest is 5.2. Anyway, I assume you're talking about service providers, if you look over the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers) it's pretty self explanatory.

Comment: ok, I'll check that, thanks